# C++ Win32 API GetMessage From Awesomium In Separate Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, message-queue, awesomium

Hello and thank you taking the time to view my question.

I am making a C++ program which uses the Win32 API to create the initial program window. I then create a thread which creates a child window and I attach my Awesomium WebView to this child window.

I understand Awesomium is not thread safe but the documentation states that it is thread safe to the point that it allows you to use Awesomium in an alternate thread as long as you are using it in the thread it was created in.

Now for the issue. I have a problem receiving input from this thread back into the WinProc. If I attempt to click my mouse inside Awesomium which is parented to this child window then I can no longer drag the main window around the screen or use the minimize/maximize/close button nor does actually clicking on anything inside the awesomium window have any effect.
I've done a lot of research and found AttachThreadInput() but that does not seem to help.

Does anyone know how I can send/receive messages to/from this thread into WinProc?

The current code is here: http://pastebin.com/i4kNHcch

Thank you very much your time is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code, please, we can offer much more concrete advice or perhaps point out where you went wrong if we see what you've already tried.

Comment: maybe it's me, but "allows you to use Awesomium in an alternate thread as long as you are using it in the thread it was created in"... what?

Comment: Awesomium is not thread safe, you cannot use different parts in different threads, you can however use it in an alternate thread as long as it is used completely in that thread. Im uploading to pastebin now.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/i4kNHcch

Comment: Why do you want the web view in a separate thread? Is there a windows message loop running in the dedicated thread?

Comment: I'm making a 3D game and need the windows GUI stuff in it's own thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could have nothing to do with the Awesomium being not thread safe. With a main window in one thread and a child window in another thread Windows can deadlock. The parent and child windows need to communicate with each other (inside the OS) and they are not designed to communicate out-of-thread.

Comment: I've tried having the child window created in the main thread and it had no apparent effect.

Comment: You are correct, I had to make Awesomium render from within my 3D engine instead of on top of it, I use http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/